# Lower bound $\mathcal{K}$-class function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $\alpha_0: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a $\mathcal{K}$-function, i.e., a strictly increasing function such that $\alpha_0(0) = 0$, and $b \geq 0$ a given constant. Is there any way to lower bound what follow

$$
\alpha_0(x) + b \geq \alpha(x + b)
$$

with a $\mathcal{K}$-function $\alpha$? I guess this should be a well-known result, any suggestions for some related theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a $\mathcal K$-function $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(x+b)\le\alpha_0(x)+b$.

Notice that $\alpha_0(x)+b$ is a strictly increasing function. So one would think of letting $\alpha(x+b)=\alpha_0(x)+b$. In other words, we take $\alpha(x)=\alpha_0(x-b)+b$ for $x\ge b$.

We need to define $\alpha$ on $[0,b]$ as well! Well notice that $\alpha(b)=b$, so any strictly increasing function such that $\alpha(0)=0$ and $\alpha(b)=b$ will do.

Comment: Exactly, I was passing by a change of variables and I was getting the same result. It seems work,

Comment: Yep it works :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it works also for some given $b<0$.

Comment: Well pay attention $\mathcal K$-functions are defined on the nonegative real numbers.

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunately, the same procedure does not apply.

Comment: @Scientifica Do you think there is a similar result for a class KL function? I can ask it more formally, if there isn't a straightforward answer to it.

Comment: @Guangyao Sorry for the late answer; I'm not very active on MSE. I'm not familiar with this topic; I didn't know about K functions until I saw the question (it's an easy definition though, so I could answer).
So I'm not aware about what kind of generalisations would be useful for KL functions (I rely on the definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_kappa-ell_function)). If you ask me about a generalisation, the most straightforward one that comes to my mind is the following:

Comment: Let $\beta_0\in\mathcal{KL}$ and $b\ge 0$. Then there exists $\beta\in\mathcal{KL}$ such that $$\forall (r,s)\in{\displaystyle \operatorname {dom} (\beta_0)},\,\beta_0(r,s)+b\ge\beta(r+b,s).$$

Comment: For the proof, if you fix $s$, the function $r\mapsto\beta_0(r,s)$ belongs to the class $\mathcal K$, so you can construct the function $r\mapsto\beta_s(r)$ in class $\mathcal K$ in a similar manner as done in my answer to the OP's question, except that you should make sure that the conditions on $s$ are satisfied to have the final function $\beta$ in $\mathcal KL$.

Comment: You might notice that the proof I gave for OP's question holds for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, whereas in the definition I linked for functions of class $\mathcal KL$, the domain is $[0,a)\times\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, so if you fix $s$ you get a function having domain $[0,a)$ rather than $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. This is not a problem as you can consider any increasing homeomorphism between $[0,a)$ and $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.